# Email address sanitisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, sanitization

In my Ruby on Rails web site, I sometimes got invalid email addresses that containing non-ascii dot or soft hyphen (%C2%AD). What I did is to remove the invisible spaces and soft hyphens and replace the wrong dot (".") to ascii dot. I'm wondering how the others handle these invalid email addresses? Is there a standard way of sanitising the email addresses?

Comment: Slightly off-topic: don't attempt to validate email addresses with regex. https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/